# Python optimize with multithreads?

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, optimization, parallel-processing

I'm sorry if I post this on the wrong forum, but is there any way to improve my code to run faster with multi-threads, processes or other improvements?

The purpose of this script is to find all possible words for a scrabble game based on the word you type in and calculate it's scrabble score.

When I enter a word that has more than 7 characters, it takes forever to make the computations.

```
scores = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

WORDS = []
combs = dict()

def prepareDict(file):
    try:
        f = open(file, 'r')
        for line in f:
            WORDS.append(line.rstrip().lower())
    except OpenErrors:
        print("Could not open file")
    finally:
        f.close()

def combinations(word):
    for i in range(len(word)+1):
        combList = itertools.permutations(word, i)
        for item in combList:
            item = ''.join(item)
            if item in WORDS:
                value = 0
                for c in item:
                    value += int(scores.get(c))
                combs[item] = value
    return (combs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
prepareDict('sowpods.txt')
if len(sys.argv) > 2 or len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("usage: %s <word>" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    word = sys.argv[1].lower()

combs = combinations(word)
sorted_combs = sorted(combs.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for word in sorted_combs:
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `WORDS = []` into a `set()`:

```
WORDS = set()
```

then change the method to add words to it:

from:

```
WORDS.append(line.rstrip().lower())
```

to:

```
WORDS.add(line.rstrip().lower())
```

No reason to use a list for that. This should improve performance.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That really did improve the performance! Thanks alot.